# Write column data from csv in to a line / row in a text file

Tags: python, csv

im working in a script to read a .csv file , read an specific column and write it in a txt file, the problem is, that the extracted data is written in a column, in this form:

```
primary_channel
2
1
0
0
2
0
1
2
1
```

and i need it in a line,like this:

```
2,1,0,0,2,0,1,2,1
```

my code is the next,

```
import sys
import csv
import copy
import os
import random
import fileinput
import sys, glob
from io import StringIO
from collections import OrderedDict
import sys
#scriptname,f1name,f2name=sys.argv

fieldnames=['node_code;node_type;wlan_code;destination_id;x(m);y(m);z(m);primary_channel;min_channel_allowed;max_channel_allowed;cw;cw_stage;tpc_min(dBm);tpc_default(dBm);tpc_max(dBm);cca_min(dBm);cca_default(dBm);cca_max(dBm);tx_antenna_gain;rx_antenna_gain;channel_bonding_model;modulation_default;central_freq (GHz);lambda;ieee_protocol;traffic_load(pkts/s)']

main={}
with open('nodos_cambiados_1.csv','r') as infile,open('lista.txt','w') as outfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(infile,delimiter=";" )
     writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile,fieldnames=['primary_channel'],delimiter=",",extrasaction='ignore')
     writer.writeheader()
     for row in reader:
         next(reader) 
         for values in row:
             if row['node_type']=='0' in row:
                main.update({row['primary_channel']:()})

         writer.writerow(row)
```

I will be very grateful for the help you can give me

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? You're very clearly just writing each row, one after the other. Have you tried combining all the data, and then writing that as a single row? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

In the call to `DictWriter`, try adding `newline=''`. As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) notes:

> Any other optional or keyword arguments are passed to the underlying writer instance.

Answer (score 1):

Using DictWriter seems like overcomplicating things, if you just want to write numbers on a row. I think something like this will suffice:

```
with open('nodos_cambiados_1.csv','r') as infile,open('lista.txt','w') as outfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(infile,delimiter=';')
     outfile.write(','.join(row.get('primary_channel') for row in reader))
```

Comment: It might be simpler, but it has a downside of loading all values into memory.

Comment: Yes, and that's a problem if you're parsing an amount of data no sane person ever puts into a CSV.

Comment: It's a problem whenever the ratio of the size of the file and available memory, is high enough. There might be several processes, several other things being stored in memory. I'm not saying that this solution doesn't have benefits, but it also has drawbacks.